# GWT UploadServlet maxSize not being respected

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I've seen this question asked a couple of times a long while back but haven't seen a solid answer so I was hoping to get a bit more information.

I am working with the `GWT UploadServlet` and running into the issue where the `512 KB file limit is reached`.  I've tried adding the context params for maxSize and maxFileSize into my web.xml to no avail.

```
<context-param>
    <!-- max size of the upload request -->
    <param-name>maxSize</param-name>
    <param-value>10240000</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <!-- max size of the upload request -->
    <param-name>maxFileSize</param-name>
    <param-value>10240000</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The `UploadServlet` still initializes on startup with the 512 KB limit it defaults to. Does anyone have any idea how to get this working correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by "GWT UploadServlet"? As far as I can tell, there isn't a class called "UploadServlet" shipped as a part of GWT. What is the full package of that class?

Comment: https://github.com/mwl/gwt-upload/blob/master/core/src/main/java/gwtupload/server/UploadServlet.java

And looks like default limit is 5mb, so maybe is your server configuration the one you need to change.

Answer (score 2):

Don't.

Seems like you are using gwt-upload, which looks like an old and unmaintained piece of software.

I would strongly suggest to take advantage of the Servlet 3.0/3.1 specs and simply post the file from the client and let the server do the dirty work.

Here there is a full explanation with examples:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2424824/2858092